# Boat Creak Sound

Tags: sound-design

Does anybody have any advice for creating the sound of of a metal fishing boat creaking?  I have a limited to no budget as this is  for a university project.

Answer (score 2):

This is sure to become a SSD running gag, but: ***Wheelbarrows***. :-)

They're constructed not unlike boats, a large metal tub or scoop, and using a shovel or even a hammer claw on the inside of a wheelbarrow's bin can yield some great groaning, creaking, etc. Plus, whenever I've been in a fishing boat on the water, things are invariably swaying and swinging, hitting the hull and making all manner of percussive sounds, so it works for that as well.

Pitched-down rusty hinges are also good for metal that's under more intense strain. Listen all around you for squeaky doors and the like, but be sure to not record them with much (any, ideally) room reverb.

WHEELBARROWS FOR EVERYONE! :-p

Comment: just got my wheelbarrow serviced, mind you

Answer (score 1):

I actually have a toaster with a door that gives a really great creak. You could try to find some of your household appliances. if it doesn't immediately creak, give it a little extra push at the bottom to try to tense it. When I'm home i may be able to try to record one, but it will be easier for you because you'll be able to get closer to the foley.

Answer (score 0):

I've got some fantastic creaks from big rusty metal jerry cans and oil drums. Using the screw caps as the source and the empty cans as a chamber, I got great reverb squeaks and creaks. Pitching them down and the frequency range drops, so they turn into groans and croaks with plenty tails to meddle with.

Something to work with, but I am not sure the exact sounds you are looking for.